# Is there a version of Dirichlet's theorem for a system of power congruences?

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I know that Dirichlet's theorem says that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p\equiv a$ (mod $n$) when gcd$(a,n)=1$. I'm wondering more generally about a system of power congruences

$x^{k_1}\equiv a_1$ (mod $n_1$)

$x^{k_2}\equiv a_2$ (mod $n_2$)

:

$x^{k_m}\equiv a_m$ (mod $n_m$)

Given fixed positive integers $k_i,a_i,n_i$ as above, is there a condition, e.g., $gcd(a_i,lcm(n_1,\ldots,n_m))=1$, that guarantees the existence of infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p^{k_i}\equiv a_i$ (mod $n_i$) for all $1\leq i\leq m$?

Maybe this should be a separate post, but I'm also wondering about conditions that guarantee that the above system has any solutions $x\in\{0,1,\ldots,L-1$}, prime or not, where $L=lcm(n_1,\ldots,n_m)$.

Comment: There are many variables here. Is $x$ the desired prime number ? Which of those variables are assumed to be given ?

Comment: I'll edit the post.

Comment: I don't think there's any simple condition on $n$ guaranteeing there's a solution to $x^3\equiv2\bmod n$. But if $n$ is odd, and if there is a solution, then Dirichlet guarantees there's a solution with $x$ being prime.

Comment: Why did you delete your previous similar question? Your congruences constraints are equivalent to $x \bmod L \in S$ for some finite subset $S\subset 0\ldots L-1$ that you have to compute. Then the density of primes satisfying those congruences is $\frac{\# A}{\phi(L)}$ where $A = \{ s\in S, \gcd(s,L)=1\}$ and if $A=\emptyset$ then only finitely primes satisfy it (as they'll divide $L$).

Comment: I deleted that one because it was a slight variant of - yet another - question that I'd posted previously. I think I understand everything now. Thank you.

Comment: Hi reuns, I'm planning to submit for publication a short paper which builds off of the principle that you elucidated for me in your comment, and I thought I should acknowledge you for aiding my understanding and ultimately helping me formulate my result. Please let me know if you have any objections to this. The acknowledgment would read something like “I thank math.stackexchange.com user 'reuns' for helping me understand the density of primes satisfying certain congruence relations.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Assume $(a_i,n_i)=1$.
Solve each
$$x^{k_i}\equiv a_i\pmod {n_i}$$
individually, [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816731/proof-of-kth-power-theorem-xk-equiv-a-pmod-n-has-a-solution-iff-a-p).

Let $x\equiv b_i\pmod {n_i}$ be one of the solutions with $(b_i,n_i)=1$.

(2) Assume $(n_i,n_j)=1$, for all $i\neq j$.

Then it becomes
$$\left\{\begin{align}
x&\equiv b_1\pmod {n_1}\\
&\vdots\\
x&\equiv b_s\pmod {n_s}
\end{align}\right.$$
Then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, the solution is unique with $$x\equiv c\pmod{ \prod_{i=1}^s n_i}.$$

(3) To have infinitely many prime solutions, we only need
$$(c,\prod_{i=1}^s n_i)=1.$$
We see that $(c,\prod_{i=1}^s n_i)=1$ if and only if
$$(c,n_i)=1\iff (b_i,n_i)=1,\quad i=1,\ldots,s,$$
which follows from (1).

(4)In conclution, with $(a_i,n_i)=1$ and $(n_i,n_j)=1$ $(1\leq i\neq j\leq s)$, if the system of congruences has a integer solution, then it has infinitely many prime solutions.